# How can I check for an installed packaged version on multiple linux hosts?

Tags: ansible

i need to check more than 100 servers for the snapd package, but I don't like the output at all. I searched all day for different options without luck. Attached is the output of ansible-playbook. Any hints guys?  [image]

```
---
 - hosts: centos
   become: true
   tasks:
    - name: Check Hostname
      command: /usr/bin/hostname

    - name: Check for package if is installed
      yum:
        list: snapd
      register: result
```

For checking the package version I tried with the following playbook but Ansible doesn't like the syntax:

```
---
 - hosts: test2
   become: true
   tasks:
    - name: Check Hostname
      command: /usr/bin/hostname

    - name: Check for package if is installed
      yum:
        list: snapd
      register: package_name_version

    - name: set package version
      set_fact:
        package_name_version: "{{ package_name_version.results|selectattr('yumstate','equalto','installed')|map(attribute='version')|list|first }}"
```

Thanks,
Juls

Comment: I simple way would be to do `ansible -i <inventory> <target group, lets' say some CentOS systems> -m shell -a "rpm -qa | grep <package name>"`; that would display a list consisting of server name and package version.

Comment: @13dimitar you should put that ad-hoc play into an answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ansible approach.**
Due to the possibility of multiple versions of the same package being installed, the package dictionary value is a list. To resolve this, simply take the first element of the list.

```
  tasks:
    - name: Gather the package facts
      ansible.builtin.package_facts:
        manager: auto

    - name: Check whether a package is installed
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "{{ ansible_facts.packages['google-chrome-stable'][0].version }}"
      when: "'google-chrome-stable' in ansible_facts.packages"
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to do:

```
ansible -i <inventory> <target group, lets' say some CentOS systems> -m shell -a "rpm -qa | grep <package name>"
```

That would display a list consisting of server name and package version.

Answer (score 0):

The ["Ansible approach"](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/package_facts_module.html) would look like this:

```
- name: Check whether a package called snapd is installed
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "{{ ansible_facts.packages['snapd'].version }} version of snapd is installed!"
  when: "'snapd' in ansible_facts.packages"
```